# Slow apk made on intel xdk

Tags: android, jquery, html, intel-xdk

I made an apk for Android using intel XDK, all based on HTML. The problem that I have is that the apk in the emulator works perfect, very fast but on real devices it works very slow, at the beginning it load the splash screen with no problem but when it get to the main page the apk take like 20 second to start running fast or normal.
I use some frame with maps and gallery of images but all go them are load in the pages not when devices start the ui framework is Jquery mobile.
I tried reducing the size of the apk but is just 8 Mb so that must not be the problem.

Comment: You might want to try using the Profile tab and see if anything sticks out as a performance bottle neck.  Do you see similar slowness in the Debug tab?  If not, you might try building it as a crosswalk app and see if that helps.  It's hard to say without more info.

Comment: I suspect you are trying to load some resources over the network, especially your maps. Your app will be limited by the network connection. Likely, your test device has a slow network connection or the resource you are trying to load is slow to respond. This is not a good practice, your app should be able to start without any network connection required. Before loading any remote resources, you need to test for a connection and then try to load in the background, rather than on the UI thread (i.e., don't do this in the initial index.html file load).

Comment: @OldGeeksGuide on debug mode happen the same very slow at the beginning but then runs ok. i will try the Profile thanks.

Comment: @xmnboy when i test on debug mode i check the use of network resources and i remove the thinks tag may be doing trouble but the problem continues the index html is just some buttons whit and image on back ground the frames whit maps are on sub pages. than for the information

Comment: Nicolas - add the init-dev.js file to your project, you'll find it in the "Hello, Cordova" sample, and enable the logging to see the console messages. From there you can inspect the dev.isDeviceReady object to see how long it is taking to get the deviceready event. Another thought is that jQuery Mobile is the culprit. Despite its popularity, it is NOT a very good choice for Cordova apps, due to the way it modifies the DOM so much.

Comment: @xmnboy thanks for the suggestion i try the profile and it shows that most of the activities take like 100% of CPU and they are just link to other pages with just information, im confused about how to improve the performance, what other Framework you suggest.